# Is it possible to show 2 Drawer indicator in the Toolbar ? -- Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

In the app that i'm working, has 2 navigation drawer. As is usual, I have de drawer indicartor on the left side to indicate the existance of the left drawer. But as I said, I have the Right drawer, and I want to know if it's possible to put another indicador for the right one, and if it can have the same  behaviour as the left one.

Toolbar now
[image: How is now the toolbar]

Other drawer indicator in right side
[image]

Comment: It is possible, but it is (a lot) dirty work and it is not suggested by design guidelines.

Comment: I didn't like to, but... who pays... "has the reason" even if I'm trying to convince him >:(   I thoug in use the 3 dots of the menu, to open right drawer.. can be possible?

Comment: Attaching click listener will block displaying overflow menu. However, attaching material menu icon (https://github.com/balysv/material-menu from this library) should be performed by finding overflow button (in this fashion https://gist.github.com/NikolaDespotoski/6329946) and attaching the drawable to this view.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski is tehere any possibility to downlaod as Jar? The project is in eclipse  and not using Gradle :(

Comment: Yes, search maven for jar.